# WooCommerce slider with quantity and variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I should make a slider of WooCommerce products that allows me to have the display of the quantity selector and the sizes of the products as I have drawn in the attached image.

[example image made in photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlVXq.jpg)

is there any plugin that allows me to get this?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a ton of WooCommerce plugins that you can [pay for](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/) or get [for free](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-carousel-slider-for-woocommerce/). But they may not do what you want exactly.

If you want to make it by yourself you could use any JavaScript carrousel library for this.

1. You need to make a loop in your page to show the products that you want ([Exemple](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/sample-products-loop/))
2. Use a JavaScript library (ex: [SlickJs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)) and target your product listing generate from your backend
3. Manage quantity and size from JavaScript or handle those settings when the user click on the **Add to cart** button

SlickJs for example should allow your user to interact inside the slide. You may disable `draggable` settings if click inside the slides is not working well.